# Identifying papyri

Tags: text-corpus, passage-identification, papyrology

Sometime in Jan/Feb 2018, the Bodleian library published [this image](https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/792f18a2448ed88e5f4dfecc68e3902d88e2af20/c=141-0-5359-3923&r=x393&c=520x390/local/-/media/2018/04/21/USATODAY/USATODAY/636598684250585522-1.jpg) showing a number of P.Oxy. 1231 fragments with some P.Oxy. 2166(a) fragments attached. Recently, I tried to identify each and every fragment there by comparing the image with [the Grenfell-Hunt transcriptions](https://ia600204.us.archive.org/29/items/oxyrhynchusppt1000grenuoft/oxyrhynchusppt1000grenuoft.pdf) at vol. X of The Oxyrhynchus Papyri and the Lobel transcriptions from vol. 15 provided as scans [in this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5732/13) and the Lobel-Page texts, and there is one I can't find:

[image]

This appears to have only one line, and maybe a vestige below. The line seems to read ΑΤΡΕΪΔ[.

Moreover, there is this fragment, which I seem to have identified as P.Oxy. 2166(a) fr. 1 via Lobel-Page, but is not in the addenda:

[image]

So:

1. What is that first fragment?
2. Why is 2166(a) fr. 1 in vol. 17 instead of vol. 21 (i.e. the addenda)? Why are the other 2166(a) numbered this way? Are there a 2166(b) group and/or a 2166 group? Is the placement of the addenda due to them being recognized as belonging with P.Oxy. 1231 only after vol. 20 was published?